# I have a question in the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat" from "Lord of the flies"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, subjects, complex-sentences

I have a question about the sentence in **bold** below. It's from the novel [*Lord of the Flies*](https://yadi.sk/i/uPxx0YAzuTL6s).

> The boy with fair hair lowered himself down the last few feet of rock
>   and began to pick his way toward the lagoon. Though he had taken off
>   his school sweater and trailed it now from one hand, his grey shirt
>   stuck to him and his hair was plastered to his forehead. **All round
>   him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat.** He was
>   clambering heavily among the creepers and broken trunks when a bird, a
>   vision of red and yellow, flashed upwards with a witch-like cry; and
>   this cry was echoed by another.

Which is the subject of the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat"?

Which is the predicate of the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat"?

Which is the object of the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat"?

Is "the long scar" all around him?

Does the word smash mean "to hit (something) violently and very hard"?

Does "a bath of heat" mean "a bath's heat"?

Comment: You don't "*meet* a question in a sentence". Instead, you say *"I* **have** *a question* **about** *a sentence"*

Comment: Please see the duplicate and its duplicate as well.

Answer (score 4):

I believe "the long scar smashed into the jungle" is the artificial clearing created by the plane which crashed onto the island, stranding the boys there.

If he is standing in the clearing then you could say that the clearing "is all around him".

"a bath of heat" is a metaphor which is saying that the air (in the clearing) is so hot that it's like being in a bath (that contains hot water).  Or, more simply, it's just saying that he is "bathed" in heat.

Comment: @Max Williams Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Max Williams                                                                                  Which is the subject of the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat"?

Which is the predicate of the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat"?

Which is the object of the sentence "All round him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat"?                                 Thank you so much for your help again.   I really appreciate it.